# Linux shell command to compare two directories and remove dupes

Tags: linux, rsync

As a part of an app I'm developing, I need to remove any files in directory A that are already into directory B. I thought of rsync but I can't stop it from copying the files missing from source to destination.

An example of what I'm looking for

i.e.

```
    /dir1/apple
    /dir1/orange
    /dir1/banana
```

And

```
    /dir2/orange
```

**After the command, I'd have:**

```
    /dir1/apple
    /dir1/banana
```

And

```
    /dir2/orange
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over each file in directory 2 and try to remove the equivalent with the same filename (`basename`) in directory 1.

```
for f in dir2/*; do echo rm -f -- dir1/"$(basename "$f")"; done
```

Note that `rm -f` does not error on files that aren't found. Remove the `echo` when you're sure it would remove the right things.

If you only want to call `rm` on existing files, test if they're in `dir1` with `[[ -f … ]]`.

```
for f in dir2/*; do del=dir1/"$(basename "$f")"; [[ -f "$del" ]] && rm -- "$del"; done
```